# C scanf() function, how to terminate on EOF/EOT?

Tags: c, scanf

I wrote a simple program to test the scanf() function in C. It basically reads from the terminal, `char` by `char`, **reprinting** the `return value` and the `char` read; and to terminate if EOF/EOT is met or if a `\n newline` is read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
    char c; int ret;

    printf("Enter the chars to test: ");

    //LOOP (scan & print) only when return is not EOF and char is not newline
    while ( ((ret = scanf("%c", &c)) != EOF) && c!='\n' ) {
        printf("%i %c\n", ret, c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It terminates correctly, if newline (`Enter`) is pressed. But the it won't just terminate with a single `Ctrl-D`. A single `Ctrl-D` will flush the typed 'chars' and printing them. Then after that it will wait again for input, although an `EOF` has been sent with the `Ctrl-D`. If we press `Ctrl-D` again the 2nd time directly after the 1st (2x) or just `Enter` it will terminate. So you will need two consecutive `Ctrl-D` to terminate the program (or the loop in this case).

Example:

If you input **`987`** on the terminal, then press **`Enter`**; then **`1 9`**, **`1 8`**, **`1 7`** will be printed on newline each.

If you input **`987`** on the terminal, then press **`Ctrl-D`**; then **`1 9`** will be printed on the same line (because there is no `Enter` typed after inputing the **`987`** input), **`1 8`**, **`1 7`** will be printed on newline. Then it will still wait for more inputs, unless it is terminated by directly entering a 2nd consecutive **`Ctrl-D`** or with a newline (**`Enter`**). So it (the program) will only stop (exit the loop) after a `newline` or 2nd consecutive `Ctrl-D`.

I am confused. Shouldn't a single `Ctrl-D` sent stop the loop here? What should I do to stop the program (scanf loop) after receiving just a single `Ctrl-D`?

I tested the code on Lubuntu 19.10 with gcc 9.2.1.

Comment: I think this is basically tied to the fact that stdin is typically endline-buffered, correct me if that's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is `scanf()` does not return `EOF` until there is no more input waiting and `EOF` is encountered. (your `"%c"` *conversion specifier* will otherwise accept any character, including the `'\n'` character, as valid and consider it a successful conversion)

When you type a line of characters, e.g. `"abcdefg"` and attempt to press <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (indicating end-of-input), the input (`"abcdefg"`) is processed and when `'g'` is reached, then `scanf()` blocks waiting on your next input. (because a successful conversion took place and no matching or input failure occurred)

Once <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> is typed a 2nd time (indicating end-of-input), when there is no input to process, `EOF` is reached before the first successful conversion and an *input-failure* occurs,`scanf()` then returns `EOF`.

See: [man 3 scanf -- **RETURN VALUE** section](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and [C11 Standard - 7.21.6.2 The fscanf function(p16)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p16)

Comment: Well, ur explanation make sense. But I am confused, how could I terminate the program (scanf & printf loop) with just a single **Ctrl-D**. Anyway Ctrl-D is a End of Transmission/Input signal right? So how can the scanf() still waits for the next input after 'g' is reached in ur example. I think that is quite big questions for C's designers..

Comment: `scanf()` blocks waiting for input. When you use `[Ctrl+d]` you generate an `end-of-input` (or `end-of-transmission`) and that basically says "I'm done entering input". `scanf()` then attempts to *process* what is there. If there is input, it is processed by `scanf()` your `EOF/EOT` has done it's job. It told `scanf()` you were done entering and it should start processing. If there is NO input to process, then `scanf()` says "Hey, you said you were done with input and there is none there, so `EOF`"

Comment: An alternative is putting the keyboard (terminal) in non-cannonical (raw) mode so that each character is processed as it is typed without waiting for a `'\n'` or `EOT` - then using `getchar()`, your manually generated `EOF` will be seen on one go.

Answer (score 0):

Test the returned value for one, not `EOF`. When eof is reached first time, zero is returned. The next scanf after zero returns `EOF`.

```
while ( ((ret = scanf("%c", &c)) == 1) && c!='\n' ) {
    printf("%i %c\n", ret, c);
}
```

This behavior is specified for the standard C library.

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items **or be less (even zero)** due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the *end-of-file*.
>
> If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror).

You can add `if (feof(stdin) != 0) break;` into the loop body, if you use more complex input format.

If you read chars only, is it not better use `fgetc`?

Comment: Why does it return 0? Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: Better test: `<= 0` or `!= 1` because `scanf` can return EOF before returning 0.

Comment: It doesn't work for me `(comparing ret != 0)`. It still requires a 2nd **Ctrl-D**. The first **Ctrl-D** didn't even seem to set a return value. The 2nd **Ctrl-D** will make it go into infinite loop, printing -1 for the 'ret' and the last successful `char c` read.

Comment: Nope, `==1` doesn't work too. (Still needs the 2nd `^D`). Idk why, seems scanf return value is a pretty tricky one.. =((