# Clearing the buffer not working as expected?

Tags: c, scanf, buffer, eof, getchar

I have the following code.

```
           int x1, x2;
           char check[3];
           do{
                //input should be (x1,x2)
                successfully_inputed = scanf("(%d,%d%2s", &x1, &x2, check);
                if(successfully_inputed == EOF)
                        break;
                if(check[1] || successfully_inputed != 3 || check[0] != ')'){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid line");
                        
                        char ch;
                        while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');

                        continue;
                }
                getchar(); // remove the new line character from buffer
          }while(1);
```

It does work for every input i give other than a particular one. When i give anything and then followed by the `EOF`, for example "asdEOF" then it consumes "asd" and when it reaches `EOF` it asks me for input, not the `scanf()` but the `getchar()`. Why is this happening and how can i solve it?

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`.

Comment: changing ```ch``` to ```int``` didn't solve it @dbush

Comment: This looks like some kind of psuedo-code. Can you give us real code we can compile and run ourselves?

Comment: edited it. if you want more code, i can provide more, i just wanted to keep it clean and simple. @pmacfarlane

Comment: Similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60843089/c-scanf-function-how-to-terminate-on-eof-eot). You should probably check `if (feof(stdin)) break;` after your `scanf()`. (This fixed your problem for me, once I got your code to compile.)

Comment: This probably isn't the advice you're looking for, but: flushing the input buffer is very nearly impossible, and it isn't worth it, because it's only necessary in the first place if you're trying to use `scanf` to do input.  If you're still using `scanf` to do input, just don't worry about flushing the input, just don't worry about handling bad input for now.  If you want to handle bad input, you can't do it with `scanf`: use [something better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537).  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215).

Comment: When you say "asdEOF" do you mean that literal string.  Usually, you trigger  EOF with ctrl-d (or an input stream ending).

Comment: yes, that's how i do @AllanWind

Comment: Sorry, not clear what you meant.  You shouldn't look at check[1] before you know scanf() was successful (i.e. returned 3).  If I give your program the literal input "asdEOF" it gives me "Invalid line" as it didn't match anything, then goes back to scanf().

Comment: if the input was correct, then check[1] should have ```'\0'```, that's why i check it. the input has to be (x1,x2). why should i check it?

Comment: check[1] is uninitialized till scanf() returns 2 or 3.  If your input is "asd<ctrl-d>" then your program is hanging on the flush getchar() waiting for input instead of getting the EOF at least in gdb.

Comment: it does give "Invalid line" but then you type 2 other lines before it gives "Invalid line" again. i also checked it with the gdb and saw that ```getchar()``` asks for input @AllanWind

Comment: It works if you do `echo -n asd | ./a.out` but hangs when it's an interactive tty.

Comment: The short of it is that you need to type ctrl-d twice as the first one will not close the stream. "On linux Ctrl-D only works when the buffer is already empty otherwise it just flushes it. Therefore unless he has pressed enter without any characters after that, he will have to press Ctrl-D twice."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [End of File (EOF) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358728/end-of-file-eof-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

When the input is "asd<ctr-d>" `scanf()` fails so you need to swap the order of conditions to you check it first:

```
        if(successfully_inputed != 3 || check[1] || check[0] != ')'){
```

In either case we are correctly getting an "Invalid line".  Then we try to flush the input stream (ensuring ch is int):

```
int ch;
while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');
```

This result in getchar() reading the 'a' and 's' and 'd' then hanging waiting for input.  This is because, on Linux, the ctrl-d only cause the terminal buffer to be flushed, and you need a 2nd ctrl-d on an empty stream to close it.  This will then trigger EOF being returned by getchar().

Even if you switch to reading input with `fgets()` it will not return till you press ctrl-d twice on non-empty input buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LINE_LEN 100
#define CHECK_LEN 3

int main() {
    for(;;) {
        char line[LINE_LEN];
        if(!fgets(line, LINE_LEN, stdin)) {
            if(feof(stdin)) break;
            // handle error
            return 1;
        }
        int x1;
        int x2;
        char check[CHECK_LEN];
        int rv = sscanf(line, "(%d,%d%2s", &x1, &x2, check);
        if(rv != 3 || check[1] || check[0] != ')') {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nInvalid line\n");
        }
    }
}
```

and example session:

```
$ ./a.out
asd<ctrl-d><ctrl-d>
Invalid line
$
```

```
$ ./a.out
<ctrl-d>
$
```